# How to set Code::Blocks on Ubuntu 22.04.1 to use the C++20 standard?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, codeblocks

GCC and g++ 11.3.0, when I enter `g++ --std=c++20` or `gcc --std=c++20` it doesn't return an error. But in Code::Blocks Compiler Settings, Compiler Flags tab, General section the only options for g++ are `Have g++ follow the 1998 GNU C++ language standard (ISO C++ plus GNU extensions)` and `Have g++ follow the 1998 ISO C++ language standard`, there is also `Have gcc follow the 2017 ISO C language standard` but I don't think that one is related to C++ and it isn't the 2020 standard anyway.

By right clicking on the options I can add new flags but there are many options that I don't know what I'm supposed to fill into.

Comment: What version of cb are you using? You should install the latest nightly build.